# How to identify user when client makes calls?

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-3.1

I have custom cookie authentication working. I think I can also get server-side authorization working. The trouble I am having is with client-side authorization. (IE: how does the *client* know what can or can't be accessed?)

So, for example, say there is a feature that is restricted to only some users. In my user data, I can have a flag that indicates which users can or can't access the feature. I can then set a role value at login indicating that users that can access that feature belong to a particular role. I can then set an Authorize attribute on the handler method to say that only users with that role can access that handler.

This prevents unauthorized users from calling that handler (theoretically; I have yet to test that but it seems like it should work). But, client-side, where I am building the UI, how can I know whether to add that feature into the UI or not?

I could return a UserInfo object to the client-side, telling the client what they are or aren't allowed to do, and then build the UI accordingly. The problem with this is that it requires saving that data between page refreshes. I would have to put it in local storage, or indexed DB, or something like that.

I could have an AJAX handler that lets the client ask whether it is allowed to do something. I think this seems like the best approach, but then I have to somehow identify the user. Again I would be left with the problem that the user needs to remember some user information (at least a username or userID) in order to identify themselves to the AJAX method.

It seems like this is exactly what the Authentication Cookie value is for. And indeed, as far as I know it is sent with every request already. So all I would need to do is retrieve that value server-side, once at login, so that I can remember which auth cookie is associated with which user (and so can or can't access certain features), and then retrieve it on future AJAX calls, to compare with the user database.

So the question then is, how do I retrieve this value? I think that I can retrieve it from a future request via something like:

```cs
var authKey = HttpContext.Request.Cookies[MyAuthCookieName];
```

But how do I remember it in the first place when it is generated? Apparently I cannot read Response cookies; they can only be added or deleted. How do I get the uniquely identifying value from the auth cookie when it is generated? It should be something like this, but it doesn't work:

```cs
var claims = new List<Claim> {
   new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username)
};

if (canAccessFeature)
   claims.Add(
      new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "FeatureRole")
   );

var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(
   claims,
   CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme
);

var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
   CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
   principal,
   new AuthenticationProperties {
      IsPersistent = true
   }
);

var cookie = HttpContext.Response.Cookies[MyAuthCookieName]; // ERROR: cannot index
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I realized that I can access the user information via the `User` property on the `PageModel`. You can use the `IsInRole` method to test whether you added the user to a role.

Rather than save information client-side you can just have a handler that tells you if you are in a role, so that the client can know whether to build the UI one way or the other:

```cs
public IActionResult OnGetCanUseFeature() =>
   new JsonResult(
      User.IsInRole("FeatureRole")
   );
```

For protecting the actual handler, note that the `[Authorize]` attribute does not work on Razor pages at the handler level. But you can simply ask if the user is in a role, and can return a 403 status result if not:

```cs
public IActionResult OnPostRestrictedFeature() {
   if (!User.IsInRole("FeatureRole"))
      return new StatusCodeResult(403);

   ...
```